# Broadcom wireless device not detected in ubuntu 12.10 but does in the live cd

Tags: 12.10, wireless, broadcom

I have a dell vostro 1400. I have installed Ubuntu 12.10 in it from live usb. I have tested from the usb and everything worked fine. I decided to install it to my hdd and after that my wifi device in not detected in the additional drivers tab which was there in the tab on the live usb. So how to enable the device again in my system. I can still use the device from the live usb.

Comment: Have you checked if a propriatary driver is available (in the "aditional drivers" tab of the Software Sources App)?